# Violation of the Weierstrass’ Extreme Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, compactness

The Weierstrass’ Extreme Value Theorem states that that given a compact subset $K$ $\subseteq$ $\mathbb{R}^n$ , if $f$: $\mathbb{R}^n$ $ \to $ $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $K$, then exists points $a$,$b$ $\in$ $K$| $f(a)$ $\leq$ $f(x)$ $\leq$ $f(b)$, $\forall$ $x$$\in$$K$.

Could you give me two examples on it? One basic illustrating the theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$  = $\mathbb{R}$. And another with violation of the assumptions ($K$ is compact and $f$ is continuous on $K$). The theorem is a bit messy in my mind because I can't clearly visualize what is happening.

Comment: The theorem just says that an $\Bbb R$-valued function that's continuous on a compact set actually achieves both its minimum and maximum somewhere on the set.  And the theorem holds in full generality for *any* compact set $K$ in *any* topological set.  On non-compact sets, the theorem could "break" in one of two ways.  The function might be unbounded or, if it's bounded, it might never actually achieve the bound.  An easy example of each is the function $f(x)=x$ on the non-compact spaces $(0, 1)$ (never actually achieves its bounds) and $[0, \infty) (not bounded above)$.

Answer (score 1):

In all the following we take functions $\;f:[0,1]\to \Bbb R\;$:

$$\text{Examples:}\;\;\;\;f(x)=x\,,\;\;\; f(x)=x^2\;$$

$$\text{Counterexamples:}\;\;\;\;f(x)=\begin{cases}\log x\,,\,\,x\neq0\\{}\\1\,,\,\,\,\,x=0\end{cases}\;,\;\;f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1x\,,\,\,x\neq0\\{}\\1\,,\,\,\,\,x=0\end{cases}$$

Find the maximum and/or minimum values in the first two, and show there are not such values for the last two.

Comment: Thanks! Now it is clear. With counterexamples is much easier to understand. The core part of the theorem is on "for all object in K", and on the last two examples, it fails for some points.